# Como adicionar um atributo com JSTL sob uma condição?

Tags: html, jstl

```
<div class="body">
   <selected name ="multSelectSkill" id="optgroup" class="ms" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="GRUPO 1">
       <c:forEach items="${skillsOperador}" var="skillsOperador">
          <option value="${skillsOperador.id}" selected="${skillsOperador.operadorSkill.statusSkill == 'Y'}>${skillsOperador.nome</option>
```

É possível utilizar o atributo dessa forma? Pois não está funcionando; está selecionando todos os valores. Eu preciso selecionar somente os valores que possuem o `statusSkill` igual a `Y`;

Comment: Que linguagem é essa? Outra coisa: procure não colocar prints de códigos em suas perguntas. Ao invés disso, cole o código propriamente dito. Isso facilita para pessoas que usam a busca do site.

Comment: Estou utilizando JSTL no html.

Comment: @KennedyAnderson Coloque a tag adequada à tecnologia que você está usando na pergunta. Assim você terá uma chance maior de ela chegar até alguém que sabe a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, estou realizando as alterações necessárias.

Comment: Quão sentido faz você definir o valor de `var` igual à `items` na tag `forEach`? Isso não iria sobrescrever a variável? Tente fazer algo como: `${var.statusKill == 'Y' ? "selected" : ""}`

Comment: Não interfere em nada o nome da var, pois funciona em outras paginas, como a "criar operador".

Mas posso testar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um ternário para verificar a condiação faça com que ele escreva ou não o `selected`, da forma que está sempre é adicionado o `selected="false"` fazendo com que todos os elementos tenham esse atributo.

```
<option value="${skillsOperador.id}"  ${skillOperador.operadorSkill.statusSkill == 'Y' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${skillsOperador.nome}</option>
```

Melhor visualização:

```
<option value="${skillsOperador.id}"
   ${skillOperador.operadorSkill.statusSkill == 'Y'
   ?
      'selected="selected"'
   : 
      ''
   }>
${skillsOperador.nome}</option>
```

Comment: Fica mesmo sem o "value" ?

Comment: @KennedyAnderson tem o value sim, omiti ele pq copie o código da imagem postada.

Comment: Certo.

Testei dessa forma :
<option value="${skillsOperador.id}" selected="${skillsOperador.operadorSkill.statusSkill == 'Y' ? 'selected='selected' : ' '}">

Mas não funcionou e quando atualizo a pagina algumas vezes, apresenta erro 500.

 /pages/cadastro/AlterarOperador.jsp (line: [241], column: [86]) Unterminated [${] tag

Comment: @KennedyAnderson vc não pode deixar o `selected` fixo no html

Comment: Ola @rray, boa noite!

Tentei utilizar dessa forma, mas retorna erro quando acesso o operador para alterar.


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "?" "? "" at line 1, column 51.

Comment: No código que você sugeriu eu adicionei uma apostrofe no selected.

'selected'="selected"

Pois sem ele o código nem roda.

Comment: @KennedyAnderson verdade faltou fechar uma aspa simples mesmo.

Comment: como faço para fechar essa pergunta ?

Comment: @KennedyAnderson marque com o sinal verder a resposta que resolveu o seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Caros, boa noite.

Primeiramente obrigado pela a ajuda. Consegui resolver o problema.

Basicamente eu verifico primeiro os que valore que possuem a chave "Y" e se existir, já dou um 'selected' neles. Se não, eu listo conforme padrão.

Muito obrigado a todos.

```
<select name="multSelectSkill" id="optgroup" class="ms" multiple="multiple">
   <optgroup label="GRUPO1">
   <c:forEach items="${skillsOperador }" var="skillsOperador">
      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${skillsOperador.operadorSkill.statusSkill eq 'Y' }">
            <option value="${skillsOperador.id }" 
            selected="${skillsOperadorPorto.id }">${skillsOperadorPorto.nome }
            </option>
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
            <option value="${skillsOperador.id }">${skillsOperador.nome}
            </option>
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
   </c:forEach> 
   </optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que expressões não sejam aceitas.

Faz essa verificação antes de mandar os dados por HTML, daí tu já traz a variável com o valor pronto. E ela precisa trazer "selected" ou "" pra você escrever o próprio atributo, pois se ele estiver presente no option, independentemente do value, o elemento será selecionado.

eg.

```
<option value="${skillsOperador.id}" ${skillsOperador.operadorSkill.attrSelected} >
```

sendo o  valor de skillsOperador.operadorSkill.attrSelected ou "selected" ou "".

Comment: Vi aqui que expressões são aceitas sim, usa um ternário então.

Comment: Entendi, vou verificar então.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ainda não consegui com o ternário =\

Comment: O código esta dessa forma:

<option value="${skillsOperadorPorto.id } ${skillsOperadorPorto.operadorSkill.statusSkill eq 'Y' ? 'selected' : ''}">

Só que ele não esta selecionando os valores que possuem "Y" como atributo.

Comment: Você pode fazer essa verificação no Java mesmo, ao invés de usar a variável statusSkill você pode trazer outra onde já exista o valor "selected" ou "" ao invés de 'Y' ou 'N'. Daí evita de usar o ternário do JSTL.